# is there a way to kill buffers when using the `switch-to-buffer` view

Tags: buffers, kill-buffer

when using `C-x b` followed by `TAB`, a list of buffers are brought up. Is there a way to quickly kill the buffers that are not needed (by pressing `<delete>` or `d`) on the selected buffer?

Comment: Try the ibuffer package instead.

Comment: Yes if you are using ivy (which I totally recommend).  This binds C-x b to `ivy-switch-buffer` and then, hitting M-o during buffer selection offers a range of actions including killing the selected buffer.

Comment: Also yes if you use the builtin `ido-mode`. When you activate the mode it rebinds `C-x b` to `ido-switch-buffer` and when you run it you can press `C-k` to kill the buffer at the head of the completion list.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "the selected buffer" here? In vanilla Emacs, `C-x b TAB` does not let you select/choose more than one buffer, and it just switches to that chosen buffer.

If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then `C-x b TAB` lets you cycle among or otherwise move to any of the buffer-name candidates. You can then use `S-<delete>` to delete the buffer named by the current (selected) candidate.

Similar possibilities exist with some other packages that also provide a way to cycle or otherwise navigate to (select) a buffer-name candidate. This includes Ido (from vanilla Emacs), Helm, and Ivy.

In Icicles you can also use `C-x k`, filter buffer-name candidates in various ways, and then use `C-!` to kill all of the remaining candidate buffers at once.

See [Icicles - Buffer-Name Input](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Buffer-Name_Input).